# Any chance to change word selection separator characters in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

Is it possible to change word delimiters in RStudio? In particular, is it possible to make the underscore (`_`) and the dot (`.`) to act as the word delimiters, too?

Comment: Ignoring `_` and `.` as word delimiters is so annoying that I think I will write some AHK script to bypass default reaction... Also ctrl+up ctrl+down is broken on Windows. Sometimes it scroll editor, sometimes it jump to nearest function definition.

Comment: It would be even better if word delimiters could be camelCase sensitive.